# Does the measured mass of earth include that of the atmosphere?

Tags: mass, measurements

Just what the title states please... and perhaps naive too...

Wikipedia pegs the mass of our Earth at 5.9722 × 10^24 kg.

Does this figure include the mass of the Atmosphere?

Comment: The difference is (just) past the last digit of accuracy in your number, so it is  impossible to tell.

Comment: Then would it be fair to say the atmospheric mass is, for all practical purposes, negligible?

Comment: If you consider this accuracy sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is (just) past the last digit of accuracy in your number, so it is impossible to tell.

You can estimate the fraction of the mass of the atmosphere by the ratio of the atmosphere's height to the radius of the earth (which gives the order of magnitude of the fraction of the Earth's volume in the atmosphere, about 10km/6000km, or 1/600), times the ratio of density of gas to ordinary solid (which is about 1/300). This gives 1 part in $10^{-5}$, and this is an overestimate, because the Earth's core is much denser than an ordinary solid because of the immense pressure. The mass figure you quote is correct to about 1 part in $10^{-5}$, so it is not clear if it includes the atmosphere or not, because this is a negligible error.

The mass of the Earth is found by measuring g, and the 1 part in $10^{-5}$ (or less) variations due to the atmosphere as you go up will be hard to distinguish from oblateness corrections, or just experimental error.

#### Atmospheric pressure

Multiplying standard atmospheric pressure by the surface area of the Earth gives the mass of the atmosphere as $5 \times 10^{18}Kg$, which is almost exactly 1 part in $10^{-6}$ of the mass of the Earth that you quote.

Comment: you have an error in the sign of your exponent of the atmosphere's mass.

Answer (score 3):

The mass of the earth [can be and has been measured](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/astronomy/planets/earth/Mass.shtml) using Newton's law of gravity. For the original experiment see [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment). The method by construction excludes most of the atmosphere, and the value is valid below the radius where it is measured.

Measurements from space include the atmosphere and I expect that [this NASA experiment](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/305/5683/503.abstract) exploring mass differences will also be giving the mass of the earth including the atmosphere. In any case the [mass of the atmosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth) with respect to the rest of the globe is

> The average mass of the atmosphere is about 5 quadrillion (5×10<sup>15</sup>) tonnes or 1/1,200,000 the mass of Earth

One should worry only if one is measuring with accuracy greater than this, as in the following fascinating experiment:
 I found this [NASA experiment](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2011/04may_epic/), which confirms general relativity and uses mass differences.

Comment: Well, the mass of Earth can be and has been measured by Kepler's method as well – from the orbit of the Moon – and this method makes it completely clear that the atmosphere, like anything else linked to Earth, is included just like the bulk of the Earth.

Comment: The website anna v references does not seem to be very trustworthy. Cavendish never computed G, as they claim, G was invented about 100 years after Cavendish died. Wikipedia is very careful to make this point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Cavendish#Density_of_the_Earth.

Comment: @Zeynel I found it by google , and you may be right . It is the method that is important.

Comment: @Zeynei: Wikipedia is saying nonsense. The fact that they didn't call it "G" is immaterial. The law of universal gravitation was known, and the coefficient was known to be constant. When Cavendish measured Newtonian gravitation for masses, he knew that the same "G" would apply to all stuff. So Wikipedia is stupid here, and it is not appropriate to cite it.

Comment: @RonMaimon Who are "they" and what is "it" that they did not call "G"?

Comment: @Zeynel: The Cavendish era people, and the "it" is the coefficient of Newton's law of universal gravitation. They were aware that the gravitational force is proportional to the two masses and inversely to the square of the distance, and from this, one deduces a measurement of the acceleration of two masses toward each other plus a measurement of "g" is a measurement of the mass of the Earth. The fact that you parametrize it by using the letter "G" for Newton's constant is not important, what is important is the web of relations.

Comment: @Zeynel: I fixed the stupid statements on Wikipedia. This is atrocious history and atrocious science both--- Cavendish knew what "G" was, _everyone past Newton knew it_, and he knew very well he was measuring "G". To say otherwise is stupidity of monstrous proportions.

Comment: @Lubos: There is no way to measure the mass of the Earth from the orbit of the moon. The fact that you got two upvotes on this ridiculous comment is annoying. If you double the mass of the Earth and the Moon, and divide G by four, nothing changes. You need to measure G.

Comment: @RonMaimon Hmm. m*v^2/R=m*a , in my books. m the mass of a small satellite, so if we know its orbit and velocity then we have a to first order? correct  equations could give great accuracy.

Comment: @RonMaimon Do you have any reference you can cite in Cavendish's paper to support your claim that "Cavendish knew very well he was measuring G"?

Comment: @Zeynel: I will not give a reference--- I _never_ give references. If a reference contradicts my obvious statement that Cavendish knew he was measuring G, then that reference is too stupid to read, let alone cite.

Comment: @anna v: The difference is that you know the mass of the satellite. If you could measure the back-reaction on the Earth, you find G. But you can't because the sattelite is too small. We aren't given a reference mass in outer space. We can only determine the relative masses of the various bodies from their orbits, not a single absolute mass. The absolute scale is fixed by Cavendish.

Comment: @RonMaimon first order of magnitude: m*v^2/R= m*a . m goes out both sides and we get a=v^2/R . You need to know R of the moon to also have v^2, "a" must be g in this case. Seems R  was found even in antiquity once the diameter of the earth is known http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aristarchus_working.jpg. I would agree that once the influence on the orbit of the sun and planets is taken to account corrections might arise destroying accuracy.

Comment: @anna v: This doesn't give the mass of the moon. It gives the acceleration due to the Moon. You need "G" to get the mass from the acceleration.

Comment: @RonMaimon to go from g to G one needs the density of the earth and the radius of the earth, no? You might be arguing  that the density of the earth has a large error. Or maybe that it is a circular argument, as to get the density one needs G?

Comment: @anna v: The density and mass are synonyms, since we know the radius. I was just saying that you can't obtain a measurement of any mass from gravity without having some calibration of the force of gravity using laboratory masses, a-la Cavendish. It's not a deep point, I am sure you know it as well as I do, but I think we might be talking past each other...

Comment: @RonMaimon probably we are. I was thinking of measuring the density of the earth by seismic waves or some such, an independent measurement.

Comment: @anna v: I see--- you could get an independent measurement this way, but this requires a model for seismic propagation, which needs the equation of state of materials at impossible pressures (which we extrapolate, but I think using the known mass of the Earth both to get the pressure and to find the composition). It might be possible to mass the Earth without Cavendish, but it would be fiendishly difficult.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Your opinion that Cavendish knew he was measuring G is contradicted by Cavendish's own paper. You are saying that Cavendish's own paper is stupid to read let alone cite because it contradicts your personal opinion.

Comment: @Zeynel: Here is the paper: http://rstl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/88/469 . It obviously shows that Cavendish is measuring the gravitational force between known masses. He is therefore measuring what we now call "G". He knows the force is GMm/r^2, from Newton, he measures the force, the distance, and the masses. What is left unknown? It is only because the notation for "G" isn't standardized that you are complaining. But it is normal to express old results in modern language, when nothing is changed in doing so. Cavendish is measuring G. There is no debate.

Comment: @RonMaimon, So you are agreeing that Cavendish did not measure G by writing “C is measuring the gravitational force...” `You` interpret C’s measurement of force as measurement of G, a unit conversion factor that C was not aware of. You are also attributing to C what he did not know. C did not know GMm/r2 because he did not work with equations; C did not know G because it was not defined yet; and C did not know a unit of force. You are attributing to C all these things that he did not know by saying C knew them. This is your personal opinion and it is not supported by historical evidence.

Comment: @RonMaimon, Why is this distinction important? Because Cavendish computed the mean density of the earth without ever using a “gravitational constant”. You are saying that Cavendish could not have computed the mean density of the earth without a unit conversion factor that physicists now call G. Then, it is your burden to show in Cavendish’s paper where he uses G or a term which is equivalent to it but has a different name.

Comment: @Zeynel in the wiki article i am linking in my answer it explains why :" physicists generally do credit Cavendish with the first measurement of the gravitational constant.[25][26][27][28][29]". Check the references.

Comment: @Zeynel: It is so idiotic to claim that Cavendish did not measure G, you must be trolling. It is impossible to measure the density of the Earth in the way Cavendish did without using the fact that you are measuring "G". Please stop trolling.

Comment: @RonMaimon: There are historians who spent years analyzing the Cav. Experiment and they concluded that Cav. did not measure G. You dismiss such historical evidence as “idiotic”. And you continue to write falsehoods. Cav. did not “measure” the density of the earth by using G. Cav. “computed” the mean density of the earth without using any coefficient for force. It’s your burden to show in Cavendish’s paper a coefficient representing G. Otherwise your argument by authority against historical evidence has no credibility.

Comment: @annav: Thanks for the references. I have a lot to say about them but now take a look at the Harvard lab notes. Neither the measurement nor the calculations corresponds to what Cavendish did; Cavendish did not use equations; he did not use any coefficients for force; he computed the mean density of the earth as the multiple of density of water taken as unity. Nowhere in his computation he needed to compute any coefficients for force. To attribute a "measurement" of G to Cavendish is anachronism.

Comment: @annav: Also this lab manual `does not` claim that they measure G. Only the period and some angles are measured. G is calculated later by using measured data. “Measurement” and “calculation” are not synonyms. Therefore, G is not a measurable quantity, G must be computed or calculated from measurements. Therefore, Cavendish did not measure G, no one can, and Cavendish did not compute G because he did not use equations. Here I’ve put 10 types of evidence why Cavendish did not measure G: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CL-LxM2omxgmuG_LAqa6Gr0xt72Db3u9aIjXNjXkZ3w/edit

Comment: @Zeynel: If there is a _single historian_ that comes to this conclusion after minutes, months, or years, this historian is incompetent in the most appalling way. It takes less than a minute of reading Cavendish to see that he is measuring G, and there are no two ways about it. Using a scaling relation for volume and density is standard practice for avoiding making explicit coefficients. The coefficients are implicit in such a method. It is likely that he wanted to phrase things in a way that didn't depend on absolute units, because SI is in the future (or immediate present).

Comment: @RonMaimon: Cavendish’s paper is available for anyone to read as you linked to it yourself and the paper has no equations, no coefficients explicit or implicit. On page 511 of the paper there is the expression for density of the earth: `D=NN/10,683B`. D is the ratio of density of the earth to density of water; N is the period and B refers to divisions on Cavendish’s pendulum. I don’t see any implicit or explicit coefficients that can be interpreted as G. Where are they? Maybe you can explain? You keep attributing to Cavendish things he did not do. Why?

Comment: @Zeynel: The ratio business in the paper is taking the observed force between the balls, rescaling by the mass of the balls, and multiplying by the square of the ratio of the separation of the balls to the radius of the Earth. This gives the mass of the Earth times g. This ratio business is assuming that the law of gravity goes as the masses and falls as the square of the distance, and the scaling argument is _obviously_ entirely equivalent to giving the coefficient, because the scaling law and the equation are the same thing in different languages. It is illiteracy to not know this.

Comment: @Zeynel: Further, you are wasting people's time arguing about things without a basis for doing so. All you have to understand that the notion of a scaling law--- like the length of a pendulum goes as the square of a period--- means that measuring any one point on the scaling law gives any other point. In modern terminology, we say it determines the coefficient. Using the scaling law (which was the convention before standardized measures, and in many old papers) is _exactly the same_ as finding the coefficient. They are only describing it in different words, like writing in German vs. English.